# DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl background color

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

In a DataGridView I have some `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and I want to set a background color to the textbox that appear when I edit a cell: only to the textbox, not to all the selected cell!
I know that the editing control in a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` is a `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`, which directly derive from `TextBox` control, but if I set the BackColor property to that object it doesn't work, it remains of the color of the selected row.
Furthermore, I don't want to develop a custom textbox column, but I want find the easiest way to do that, if possible.
Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: WinForms @DanielHilgarth

Answer (score 0):

try adding a textbox manually to the cell and then set the color..

```
        TextBox txtBox1 = null;           
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells.Add(cell);

        txtBox1.ID = "txtDemo";                    
        txtBox1.CssClass = "color";

        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells.Add(cell);
        GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(txtBox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Winform i would suggest try setting

`DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` to the `Color` you need for your TextBoxColumn

```
dgv.Columns[yourColumn].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green
```

Comment: I would change the background color only for the textbox, not for the entire cell. But I think it's impossible since I make a custom cell control.